# How to compare likelihood of different distributions from data

Tags: statistics, reference-request, statistical-inference

Suppose you have a bunch of data for some observed quantity, and you have two hypotheses $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ for the probability distribution function, and suppose for simplicity that you know that one of these two models accurately represents your distribution.  For example, maybe $f(x)$ is a gaussian distribution, whereas $g(x)$ is the sum of $f(x)$ plus another normal distribution with a different mean and smaller amplitude.  This could correspond to measuring people's heights, where the null hypotheses would be that heights are normally distributed, and another hypotheses that heights have two peaks for men/women.

How would one go about comparing how likely the data comes from one model vs the other?  What would you do if you do not go in with the inherent assumption that the single normal distribution is the "more likely" one, but your data is not significant enough to rule out a normal distribution completely?

This seems like a pretty fundamental question so I'm open to reference links.

Comment: One approach would be to compare the likelihoods of the the two models given the data (e.g. a likelihood ratio test), though this gets more complicated if you do not know the parameters (e.g. means and variances) of the distributions underlying your hypotheses before you see the data, as your mixture distribution has more flexibility to be fitted to the data; there are Bayesian and other methods which would take this into account.

Comment: A mixture of two normal distributions is bimodal if the means of the two components are several standard deviations apart. So if there is a 'dip' near the center of a histogram of the data, that might be a clue that you have a mixture distribution. You might be able to use a normality test to detect a mixture distribution that is not overtly bimodal.

Answer (score 1):

**Judging Bimodality of Mixture Distributions.**

A couple of examples to illustrate my comment:

***First example.*** Means of the two normal components are
several standard deviations apart.

```
set.seed(2020)
x1 = rnorm(100, 60, 2);  x2 = rnorm(100, 70, 2)
x = c(x1,x2)
```

Combined data fail a Shapiro-Wilk test of normality.

```
shapiro.test(x)

        Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  x
W = 0.93835, p-value = 1.651e-07
```

Histogram shows bimodality. (Also, tick marks along
the horizontal axis, at individual observations,
show two clusters.)

```
hist(x, prob=T, col="skyblue2", 
     main="Bimodal Mixture")
rug(x)
```

[image]

A normality plot of the 200 values is not anywhere near linear. The 'S' shape in this
plot is typical of bimodal data.

```
plot(qqnorm(x))
  qqline(x, col="red", lwd=2)
```

[image]

***Second example.*** The means of the two components
are more nearly equal, and the standard deviations
are a little different. [Very roughly speaking, perhaps with a little exaggeration of differences, this may be more like the mixture
distribution of adult humans (men and women together).]

```
set.seed(919)
y1 = rnorm(100, 65, 2.5);  y2 = rnorm(100, 71, 3.5)
y = c(y1,y2)
```

Shapiro-Wilk test still detects non-normality (at 5% level).

```
shapiro.test(y)

        Shapiro-Wilk normality test

 data:  y
 W = 0.98212, p-value = 0.01201
```

However, a histogram does not clearly show
bimodality.

```
hist(y, prob=T, col="skyblue2", 
     main="Mixture, but not Obviously Bimodal")
```

[image]

Judging normality by looking at
historgrams is subjective. A histogram
of the same data, but with different binning,
might give a slightly different impression.
If there are not too many observations, it may
help to put tick marks along the horizontal axis to show individual observations. The histogram
with more bins seems 'uneven', but I see no
evidence of bimodal clustering among the tick
marks.

```
hist(y, prob=T, col="skyblue2", br=20,
     main="Mixture, but not Obviously Bimodal")
rug(y)
```

[image]

Here a normal probability plot does not clearly
show bimodality, but it is not as close to
linear as one would expect for normal data. Roughly speaking, this may be the reason for
failing the Shapiro-Wilk test.

```
plot(qqnorm(y))
  qqline(y, col="red", lwd=2)
```

[image]